# Given a nested uitableview, how do I smoothly continue scrolling from child uitableview to parent uitableview in one motion - see image attached

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Please see the Twitter profile page below.

Given that the layout I have suggested below is correct (it may not be and it may be done in a different way), how do you disable scrolling for the child tableView while scrolling the parent tableview until a particular point Y (position is irrelevant) and then re-enable scrolling on the child tableview in one smooth gesture?

[image: Twitter Profile Page]

Comment: Have a look at UIScrollView Delegate. Your tableViews automatically conform to this. You should disable scrolling in every child table and then look in the didScroll delegate method when to “keep” the main table “locked” (set scroll position to fixed position you determine) and instead scroll the child table by setting its scroll position. I’ve done this myself several times and it works very well and appears to be a fluent scroll motion (because you only interact with the parent scroll view)